# JQuery post to submit HTML form data to php file not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I am new to Jquery but I have done a lot with html/php in the past. What I need to do is submit for data from within a popup modal, insert that into a mysql database on localhost and then open teh next popup via javascript. As redirecting to the php page does not allow you to load js, I have looked into using jquery to post the data to my phpfile, which will then insert the data and return a code to the jquery, which will then load the next popup if the post was succesful. I have tried different tutorials, but I just cannot get the code to work. Below is my index.php file, which contains the popup form and jquery code...

```
    <div id="survey1" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-top w3-card-4">
        <div class="w3-container w3-padding-16">
            <div class="section-heading text-center">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h1>BASIC <span>DETAILS</span></h1>
                    <p class="subheading">The basics of your business and your website.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form role="form" class="login-form" method="post" action="http://localhost/basic.php" id="basicForm">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="name" id="name">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="bname" id="bname">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Type" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="btype" id="bemail">
                </div>
                <div id="response"></div>
                <button class="btn" type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1" style="width:40%; float: right;"></button>
            </form>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#basicForm').on('submit', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#submit1').prop('disabled', true);
                        var name = $('#name').val();
                        var email = $('#email').val();
                        var bname = $('#bname').val();
                        var btype = $('#bemail').val();
                        if(name == '' || email == '' || bname == '' || btype == '')
                        {
                            $('#submit1').prop('disabled', false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $.post(
                                'http://localhost/TDS/basic.php', 
                                $('#basicForm').serialize(),
                                function(data)
                                {
                                    $('form').triggered("reset");
                                    $('#submit1').prop('disabled', false);
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my php insert file...

```
<?php 
require('connection.php')

if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["name"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email"]);
    $bname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["bname"]);
    $btype = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["btype"]);

    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO Details ('Name', 'Email', 'Business Name', 'Businesss 
Type') VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$bname."', '".$btype."')";
     if(mysqli_query($con, $insert_query))
    {
        echo json_enchode(success => 1);
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_enchode(success => 0);
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please specify in what way you "cannot get the code to work"? Do you get any errors? Do you get undesired results? It helps a lot if you tell which part of the process you're stuck with. I can also see you wrote `json_enchode` in your question, the correct name is `json_encode`.

Comment: You're also wide open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: By not working I mean when I click the button to submit the form my code does nothing ‍♂️

Comment: Have you attempted any debugging? Have you put any part of the jQuery process under test with `console.log()` statements? Have you checked your network tab in developer console to see what kind of a response you're getting from the AJAX call?

Comment: Is the PHP getting called? Try to debug it, see till where it runs

Comment: To be honest  new to jquery completely and all I know is when I click the button to submit it does nothing, no data is submitted into the dB and the pages doesn't reload or load the next popup

Comment: You misspelled `json_encode`

Comment: Yeh I know but it wasn't working before I added that in anyway

Answer (score 1):

The code itself is OK, but you need to load jQuery itself.

Put this somewhere in the beginning of your HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(the tips on how to include jQuery see here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)

Except this, the code worked for me:
- The form was submitted correctly;
- The PHP endpoint received the correct POST data;

The saving to DB I didn't check, but it looks OK.
Anyways, the PHP part is out of the scope of the question.

Also, a small issue is in the code itself: there's no such method as "$('form').**triggered**('reset');", use "$('form').**trigger**('reset');" instead.

Comment: Alright thanks I've added that line in the header but still nothing happens

Comment: A wild guess, did you fill in all the form fields before pressing submit? (there's a condition in the code to do nothing if any of them are empty)

Comment: Yehh all fields were filled. I'm wondering if it's a problem with my php file somewhere?

Comment: Might be, you can use developer console in the browser. There's the "Network" tab to check if the request went to the PHP file and check what response was.

Comment: Alright I'll check that tomorrow to see if anything has been posted to php

Comment: HTML/JS code is ok for sure. What can be also wrong is the POST url: open http://localhost/TDS/basic.php in your browser and see if it is there (no 404 error).

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow too. Is it a possible problem with my query which is causing nothing to happen as I spelt encode wrong?

Comment: Update in the network tab I have a text/htnl type call to basic.php,which returns a code 302. There is then a call from jquery to reload to index.html,which I put in the code to test if it was an issue with me insert query